# Hide Footer(Pagination Div) in jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I just want to hide the pagination (footer) section from jtable.
Please help me to hide the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your page:

```
.jtable-bottom-panel,.jtable-no-data-row{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay.... You are Rock..!

Comment: Thanks @Karthikeyan. Glad to know it helped you...:)!

Comment: Vijay, Onemore thing, I don't want to show the 'No data available!' row, Is there any specific option there? Shows only the column if there is no data.

Comment: there is no such option/configuration, but yes...by CSS you can do this. Updated the answer.

Comment: @vijayP please explain how you found out the class. It will help him find solution himself. For your last comment, of course he can edit the jtable js file to disable the row creation in case of no data is available.

Comment: @Akki619, Sure. We can easily get these CSS classes by looking into generated HTML DOM structure with the help of Firebug or browser's developer tool. Also changing the jtable js file for our need is not a good option. It is doable but it will be painful in future at the time of version upgrade.

Comment: @vijayP right. of course it is painful. The right approach is to extend the plugin and modify stuff as per you need. not change the original plugin. Just wanted to get this on table.